# Replacement for BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2, fragmentstatepageradapter, fragmentstateadapter

`androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is deprecated and developers are urged to switch to `androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter`

How can we get the same functionality with FragmentStateAdapter that BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT provided?

This code below is now deprecated

```
FragmentStatePagerAdapter(
        fragmentManager,
        BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewPager2's `FragmentStateAdapter` has the same functionality as `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` (this is, in fact, the only type of behavior `ViewPager2` supports).

The [`ViewPager2` migration guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) details the exact steps needed to convert to `ViewPager2`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`

AndroidX introduces the new [FragmentPagerAdapter constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter?hl=en#FragmentPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20int)), please notice its second parameter `int behavior`.

And in fact, the [BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter?hl=en#BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT) is deprecated, so [BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter?hl=en#BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) is the only recommended style.